# Read data from Firebase real time database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

my database has the below Json structure. I wanted to read and display the student details in my UI. I use the below code to read the data. But it is not working. Can some one help me to read and display the data whenever a change occurs at the student data or a new student is added.

MainActivity.java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Get Firebase database reference
    this.mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");

    // Init user list
    ListView list = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.dataList);
    this.listAdapter = new DataListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_view_cell);
    list.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // Add listener
    mDatabase.addChildEventListener(new FirebaseEventListener(this.listAdapter));
}
```

FirebaseEventListener.java:

```
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
    User newUser = new User((String) dataSnapshot.getValue(), (String) dataSnapshot.getKey());
    if (!(userList.getUserList().contains(newUser))) {
        userList.addUser(newUser);
        userList.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

JSON:

```
 "users":{
  "Student1":{  
     "name":"Ada Lovelace",
     "id":"123"
  },
  "Student2":{  
     "name":"smith",
     "id":"870"
  }
  }
```

Comment: Can you explain in detail what isn't working? Do you get an error?

Comment: I am not able to see any data in the UI. I am not sure what changes I need to make to onChildAdded () to display the data

Answer (score 0):

Use firebase list adapter.

```
 public class CompaniesFbAdapter extends FirebaseListAdapter<Company> {


/**
 * @param activity    The activity containing the ListView
 * @param modelClass  Firebase will marshall the data at a location into
 *                    an instance of a class that you provide
 * @param modelLayout This is the layout used to represent a single list item.
 *                    You will be responsible for populating an instance of the corresponding
 *                    view with the data from an instance of modelClass.
 * @param ref         The Firebase location to watch for data changes. Can also be a slice of a location,
 *                    using some combination of {@code limit()}, {@code startAt()}, and {@code endAt()}.
 */
public CompaniesFbAdapter(Activity activity, Class<Company> modelClass, int modelLayout, Query ref) {
    super(activity, modelClass, modelLayout, ref);
}

@Override
protected void populateView(View v, Company model, int position) {
    TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name_txt);
    TextView category = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.category_txt);
    final CircleImageView imageView=v.findViewById(R.id.comp_img);
    name.setText(model.getName());
    category.setText(model.getCategory());
    Glide.with(mActivity)
            .load(model.getLogoUrl())
            .asBitmap()
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
                }
            });
    //category.setText(model.getCategory());

}

 }
```

and in main activity call it like this

```
final CompaniesFbAdapter myAdapter= new CompaniesFbAdapter(getActivity(),Company.class,R.layout.single_company_list_item,companiesQuery);
                companylistLv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```